# Helm adds release name to dependent charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have few dependencies like this

```
dependencies:
- name: some-chart
  version: "1.2.3"
  repository: "file://../some-chart"
```

And I install my chart like so

```
helm install my-chart .
```

However, it adds dependent charts my release name. so for example `server-0` pod deploys like this

```
my-chart-some-chart-server-0
```

If I only install the dependent chart on its own, for example `helm install some-chart ../some-chart` it deploys 'server-0' like this

```
some-chart-server-0
```

Is there a way to deploy dependent charts without adding release name as its  intended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some time has passed but this may be important information for other users -

As David has explained this can not be changed by helm and comes from the templates.

If you can find the following in the templates

```
{{- if .Values.fullnameOverride -}}
{{- .Values.fullnameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
```

then you can use the `fullnameOverride` for your needs.

You can override the values of the dependency by adding in the parent's (`my-chart`) `values.yaml` file the following:

```
some-chart:
 fullnameOverride: some-chart
```

As a result, the parent's chart name (`my-chart`) will be dropped from the names of the resources and you will see your `server-0` pod as `some-chart-server-0` instead of as `my-chart-some-chart-server-0`.

Answer (score 1):

This naming convention is part of the templates.  Helm doesn't add it itself, and you can't change it without changing the templates (or doing complex post-processing).

If you run `helm create`, it creates a lot of infrastructure for you.  Things like the Deployment are generally [named](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/v3.5.3/pkg/chartutil/create.go#L262)

```yaml
name: {{ include "<CHARTNAME>.fullname" . }}
```

That template, in turn, is also part of the [generated `_helpers.tpl` file](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/v3.5.3/pkg/chartutil/create.go#L423-L428) (trimmed slightly)

```
{{- define "<CHARTNAME>.fullname" -}}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride }}
{{- if contains $name .Release.Name }}
{{- .Release.Name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- else }}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

So if you `helm install some-chart ../some-chart`, the release name (the first `some-chart` argument) matches the chart name, and you get the "short" form of just the release name; but if you `helm install other-chart ../some-chart`, you'll get the `release-name-chart-name-suffix` format.

This has nothing to do with it being a dependency, only the name you're using to install the release.  Compare:

```sh
helm install some-chart ../some-chart  # using its "normal" name
helm install foo ../some-chart         # using some other name
helm install my-chart .                # "normal" name of parent, not dependency
helm install some-chart .              # "normal" name of dependency, not parent
```

This last case should be interesting: if your parent chart uses the same convention, you will actually see names like `some-chart-my-chart-deployment`, but the `some-chart` dependency will see the release and chart names match and so within that dependency you'll just see `some-chart-foo`.